# issue at moment to run the pipeline an error appear

Tags: azure, pipeline, install.packages, msbuild-15

I am running an azure pipeline my code is on **C# .net** and **msbuild 15**, I’m having some issues at moment to run the pipeline an error appear I think is related to the packages.

**Here is the error.**

```
Package 'Sitecore.Analytics.Model.NoReferences 9.0.180604' is not found in the following primary source(s): 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\nuget'. Please verify all your online package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly.
```

[image]

I checked and I can see the pack with the correct version of the package in the path.

[image]

Any idea how to solve ? do I need to setup something in the job to run this pipe line ?

Thanks in advance.

**`install Sitecore.Analytics.Model.NoReferences -Version 9.0.180604`** checked my packages, disabled central package manager

Answer (score 0):

By Default **SiteCore** will not include **NoReference packages**, As the default packages will come with the required dependency and **DLL’s** installed. So you can directly add the SiteCore Packages from this [**official link**](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/sitecore-assembly-list-nuget-packages.html).

But as you are using external packages, You can refer this [**blog**](https://blog.jermdavis.dev/posts/2016/the-official-sitecore-nuget-feed-is-here) Create one **`nuget.config`** File in your Project or Solution with the Path to your packages.

***I have added this URL in my nuget package manager:-***

```
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/sid24desai0738/_packaging/Get-Hello/nuget/v2
```

[image]

Added `Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.NoReferences`

[image]

I have sent this Project in my Azure DevOps repository and then built it by adding one **nuget.config** file in my Repo:-

My **`nuget.config`** file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="MyCustomFeed" value="https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

***My Azure DevOps yaml code:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1


- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/nuget.config'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Make sure the package that you created is in correct path or else, And you can also run below pipeline with your feed:-

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Install NuGet'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.x'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet packages'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '<your-feed-name>'
    includeNuGetOrg: true

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    platform: 'Any CPU'
    configuration: 'Release'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Pack NuGet packages'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
    versionEnvVar: 'BUILD_BUILDNUMBER'
    includeSymbols: true
    includeSource: true
    buildProperties: 'Configuration=Release'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Push NuGet packages'
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: '<your-feed-name>'
    allowPackageConflicts: true
```

Comment: thanks so much for  you help im trying will let you know if  works for me, thank a lot